# Remove blank lines

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, angular8

I have this list:

```
export enum UserRoleType {
  masterAdmin = 'ROLE_MASTER_ADMIN'
  merchantAdmin = 'ROLE_MERCHANT_ADMIN'
  resellerAdmin = 'ROLE_RESELLER_ADMIN'
}

export const AdminRoleType2LabelMapping = {
  [UserRoleType.masterAdmin]: 'Master Admin'
};

export const MerchantRoleType2LabelMapping = {
  [UserRoleType.merchantAdmin]: 'Merchant Admin'
};

export const ResellerRoleType2LabelMapping = {
  [UserRoleType.resellerAdmin]: 'Reseller Admin'

};


public ResellerRoleType2LabelMapping = ResellerRoleType2LabelMapping;
  public roleTypes = Object.values(UserRoleType).filter(value => typeof value === 'string');
```

Dropdown:

```
<select class="custom-select" formControlName="role">
        <option [value]="roleType" *ngFor="let roleType of roleTypes">{{ ResellerRoleType2LabelMapping[roleType] }}</option>
        <div class="help-block form-text with-errors form-control-feedback" *ngIf="controlHasErrors('role')">
          {{controlValidateMessage('role')}}
        </div>
      </select>
```

I want to remove the blank lines. I tried to use only the keys like this:

```
public roleTypes = Object.keys(UserRoleType).filter(value => typeof value === 'string');
```

But I get then only blank rows.

I want to display different const based on the type of the page. But for some reason I get select menu with several blank rows and the desired list. Do you know how I can fix this? I don't want to display blank lines.

Comment: `ResellerRoleType2LabelMapping` only contains `UserRoleType.resellerAdmin` but `roleTypes` has every roles. So you will have "undefined" value when you ask `ResellerRoleType2LabelMapping[UserRoleType.masterAdmin]` for example.

Comment: Is there some solution? Maybe use another model/different structure?

Comment: Using uniq `LabelMapping` object or concat them `public labelMapping = {... AdminRoleType2LabelMapping, ...MerchantRoleType2LabelMapping, ...ResellerRoleType2LabelMapping};` and using it into the HTML `{{ labelMapping[roleType] }}`

Comment: can you show me please complete code? I don't get the idea.

Comment: This is the complete code. `...` don't mean something miss but it's a shallow copy https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: replace `public ResellerRoleType2LabelMapping = ResellerRoleType2LabelMapping;` by `public labelMapping = {... AdminRoleType2LabelMapping, ...MerchantRoleType2LabelMapping, ...ResellerRoleType2LabelMapping};` and `{{ ResellerRoleType2LabelMapping[roleType] }}` by `{{ labelMapping[roleType] }}`

Comment: Paste please official answer so that I can rate it.

Answer (score 0):

## Reason

`ResellerRoleType2LabelMapping` only contains `UserRoleType.resellerAdmin` but `roleTypes` has every roles. So you will have "undefined" value when you ask `ResellerRoleType2LabelMapping[UserRoleType.masterAdmin]` for example.

## Solution

Using uniq "labelMapping".

#### Typescript

Replace

```
public ResellerRoleType2LabelMapping = ResellerRoleType2LabelMa
```

by

```
public labelMapping = {...AdminRoleType2LabelMapping, ...MerchantRoleType2LabelMapping, ...ResellerRoleType2LabelMapping};
```

#### HTML

and replace

```html
{{ ResellerRoleType2LabelMapping[roleType] }}
```

by

```html
{{ labelMapping[roleType] }}
```

Comment: I get Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: I tried also this but without luck - the list is blank - https://pastebin.com/NsnHCwTV

Comment: Firstly if you don't put `...` it will not do a shallow copy so it will result with `{MerchantRoleType2LabelMapping: {}}` and secondly you have to copy all your LabelMappings on it.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
roleTypes = Object.values(UserRoleType).filter(value => ResellerRoleType2LabelMapping[value]);
```

So you are filtering on the role types that are in ResellerRoleType2LabelMapping

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1cukf6